# Suma de numeros con javascript y php

Tags: php, javascript

por favor necesito una ayudita, estoy tratando de sumar los valores que me devuelve un foreach ($obtenerDesEsp as $itemListaDesEsp):
pero siempre me suma el ultimo valor.
en este caso tengo 4 registros pero me suma siempre el ultimo.
Dejare mi código por favor...
Disculpen pero es la primera vez comentando así que no se como se verá mi codigo de ante mano gracias a quien me pueda ayudar.

/*Aqui esta lo de mas de mi codigo*/

```
foreach ($obtenerDesEsp as $itemListaDesEsp):

       $precioCarro =  $itemListaDesEsp['costo_promedio_producto'];
       $stockCarro =  $itemListaDesEsp['exist_actual_producto'];
?> 


<script type="text/javascript">

function operacion() {caja = document.forms["sumar<?php echo $a++?>"].elements;                                                                              
var numero1 = Number(caja["cajas<?php echo $b++?>"].value);                                                                              
var numero2 = Number(caja["precios<?php echo $c++?>"].value);                                                                             
caja["totales<?php echo $d++?>"].value = ( numero1 - numero2 );                                                                              
console.log(caja["totales"]);
                                                                              }    
</script>                  


<form name="sumar<?php echo $e++?>">
<input type="text" name="caja" id="cajas<?php echo $f++?>" value="<?php  echo $stockCarro ?>" onchange="operacion()">
<input type="number" name="precios" id="precios<?php echo $g++?>" class="form-control" value="1" style="width:60px;" min="1" max="<?php echo $stockCarro?>" placeholder="Cantidad" onchange="operacion()">
<input type="text" name="totales" id="totales<?php echo $h++?>">
</form>
<?php  
endforeach;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas una variable externa al foreach, la inicializas antes del bucle y sumas el valor que corresponda en cada ciclo, sino la reinicias cada vez que pasas por el bucle y sólo suma los últimos valores de éste

Comment: Para que sea un contador?? algo así,

Comment: Si, como si fuera un contador. Evita porner el código como imagen, despista y es muy difícil de visualizar

Comment: $g =1;              
                        $h =1;
de aqui el foreach
y al final de endforeach;
$g++;
$h++;

Comment: Puede valer, pero mejor inicia en 0, y el incremento lo haces antes del cierre del foreach, con eso ya debería salirte

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, o sea si le tenia de esa manera como me mencionas y pero igual sigue tomándome el ultimo registro si le inicializo en 0 no me auto incrementa, en fin sigue sin funcionar :( no se por que

Comment: Pon el ejemplo del cambio que hicistes que al igual no te funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema esta dado porque creas la función de `javascript` **operacion()** dentro de tu ciclo `foreach` por tanto se van a crear n veces esa misma función por lo cual cuando la llames solo va a ejecutar la última, pues se van sobrescribiendo. LO que debes hacer es sacarla del ciclo y armar mejor la logica de tu codigo.

Aquí te dejo el código modificado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function operacion(field) {
        //Obtengo el formulario
        var form = field.parentNode; 
        //Obtengo el valor del campo 1
        var numero1 = form.caja.value; 
        //Obtengo el valor del campo 2          
        var numero2 = form.precios.value;
        //Hago el calculo y se lo asigno al campo de texto correspondiente          
        form.totales.value = ( numero1 - numero2 );                                                                              
        console.log(form.totales.value);
    }    
</script>  

<?php
foreach ($obtenerDesEsp as $itemListaDesEsp):
   $precioCarro =  $itemListaDesEsp['costo_promedio_producto'];
   $stockCarro =  $itemListaDesEsp['exist_actual_producto'];
?> 

<form>
<input type="text" name="caja" value="<?php  echo $stockCarro ?>" onchange="operacion(this)" />
<input type="number" name="precios" class="form-control" value="1" style="width:60px;" min="1" max="<?php echo $stockCarro?>" placeholder="Cantidad" onchange="operacion(this)" />
<input type="text" name="totales" />
</form>
<?php  
endforeach;
```

Intenta y me dices si te funcionó.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.. @Dariel aprendí algo nuevo.
Si me funciono.

Comment: Si te funciono por favor marcala como respuesta y puntuame ;P

Comment: La puntuación es una recompensa para mi y marcarla como respuesta sirve para que otros usuarios que tengan una duda similar puedan reconocer cual de las respuesta es la adecuada. Saludos

Comment: jeje como hago para puntuar... soy nuevo en esto la verdad

Comment: Donde mismo esta la marca de que aceptastes la respuesta hay 2 flechas dale a la de arriba. Aunque por tus puntos no estoy seguro que puedas puntuar :)

Comment: creo que ya esta @Dariel por que aparece 1 jaja gracias

Comment: jajaj no hay de k para eso estamos

Comment: Hola @Dariel por favor me puedes ayudar con un codigo algo similiar a lo que me pudiste ayudar el dia de ayer?

Comment: Ponme el link de tu pregunta

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200359/suma-de-nuevos-campos-dentro-de-un-foreach ahí esta @Dariel por favor

Comment: Ya te puse el link compañero @Dariel por favor podrías ayudarme.. disculpa las molestias...

Answer (score 0):

No se si te he entendido bien. Lo que entiendo es que necesitas para cada formulario multiplicar la caja con el precio, y poner el resultado dentro del input totales. Espero haberlo acertado.

PD: el html me lo he inventado en base a tu código.

```js
let forms = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#contenedor form"));

forms.map((f) =>{
  let caja = f.querySelector(".caja");
  let precio = f.querySelector(".precio");
  let total = f.querySelector(".total");
  caja.addEventListener("input", ()=>{CalculaTotal(caja,precio,total) })
  precio.addEventListener("input", ()=>{CalculaTotal(caja,precio,total)})

})


function CalculaTotal(caja,precio,total){total.value = parseFloat(caja.value) * parseFloat(precio.value)}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
<form name="sumar1" id="sumar1">
<input type="text" name="caja" class="caja" value="15" />
<input type="number" name="precios" class="precio" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="15" placeholder="Cantidad">
<input type="text" name="totales" class="total">
</form>
<form name="sumar1" id="sumar1">
<input type="text" name="caja" class="caja" value="40" />
<input type="number" name="precios" class="precio" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="40"><!--cantidad-->
<input type="text" name="totales" class="total">
</form>
<form name="sumar1" id="sumar1">
<input type="text" name="caja" class="caja" value="20" />
<input type="number" name="precios" class="precio" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="20">
<input type="text" name="totales" class="total">
</form>
<form name="sumar1" id="sumar1">
<input type="text" name="caja" class="caja" value="10" />
<input type="number" name="precios" class="precio" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="10">
<input type="text" name="totales" class="total">
</form>
</div>
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

esta vez utilizando el valor del atributo `name``

```js
let forms = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#contenedor form"));

forms.map((f) =>{
  let caja = f.querySelector("[name='caja']");
  let precio = f.querySelector("[name='precios']");
  let total = f.querySelector("[name='totales']");
  caja.addEventListener("input", ()=>{CalculaTotal(caja,precio,total) })
  precio.addEventListener("input", ()=>{CalculaTotal(caja,precio,total)})

})


function CalculaTotal(caja,precio,total){total.value = parseFloat(caja.value) * parseFloat(precio.value)}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
<form name="sumar1" id="sumar1">
<input type="text" name="caja" class="caja" value="15" />
<input type="number" name="precios" class="precio" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="15" placeholder="Cantidad">
<input type="text" name="totales" class="total">
</form>
<form name="sumar1" id="sumar1">
<input type="text" name="caja" class="caja" value="40" />
<input type="number" name="precios" class="precio" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="40"><!--cantidad-->
<input type="text" name="totales" class="total">
</form>
<form name="sumar1" id="sumar1">
<input type="text" name="caja" class="caja" value="20" />
<input type="number" name="precios" class="precio" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="20">
<input type="text" name="totales" class="total">
</form>
<form name="sumar1" id="sumar1">
<input type="text" name="caja" class="caja" value="10" />
<input type="number" name="precios" class="precio" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="10">
<input type="text" name="totales" class="total">
</form>
</div>
```

Espero que esto funcione para ti

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, quiero copiar tu codigo para probrar, pero me da errores el javascript :/

Comment: Mira por favor el HTML. He agregado clases, También he borrado los id porque no los necesito. Si no puedes modificar el php puedo reescribir el javascript utilizando el atributo name; creo.

Comment: @JhonDi He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: yo creo ando mal.... al colocar las etiquetas <script type="text/javascript"> /*y tu código*/ </script>
ahí es donde me marca errores.

Comment: Muchas gracias @enxaneta por tu ayuda, pero ya me supo guiar mas abajo 
Gracias de verdad