# Suma de nuevos campos dentro de un foreach

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

por favor ayúdenme, necesito sumar los nuevos campos de un foreach ya que se va a modificar la cantidad actual que viene de la consulta, les dejo mi código por si alguien me puede ayudar por favor.

```
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function operacion(field) {
                                        //Obtengo el formulario
                                        var form = field.parentNode; 
                                        //Obtengo el valor del campo 1
                                        var numero1 = form.cantidad.value; 
                                        //Obtengo el valor del campo 2          
                                        var numero2 = form.precio.value;
                                        //Hago el calculo y se lo asigno al campo de texto correspondiente          
                                        form.total.value = ( numero1 * numero2 );                                                                              
                                        console.log(form.total.value);
                                    }    
                                </script> 

 <?php
     $totalProducto=0;
     foreach ($sql_Producto as $itemListarProductoCarrito):
     $precio = $itemListarProductoCarrito['costo_promedio_producto'];
  ?>
   <form>
    <table  class="table table-bordered">                                                                   
    <tr>
    <a href="eliminardelcarro.php?id=<?php echo $c["product_id"]; ?>" class="fa fa-fw fa-minus-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"></a>
    </tr>                                                                                                                          
    <tr><br>
    <!--aqui le aumento para la cantidad para poder modificar si el ususario lo desea-->
    <label>Cantidad</label>
    <select name="cantidad" style="width:100px;" class="form-control" onchange="operacion(this)" >
        <option value="<?php echo $c["q"]; ?>"><?php echo $c["q"]; ?></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>                                                                        
    </tr> 
    <tr><br>
    <td><label>Precio Unitario</label></td>
    <td><input align="right" style="width:100px;" class="form-control" type="text" name="precio" value="<?php echo $precio;/*recibo mi precio*/ ?>"  onchange="operacion(this)"  readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Total</label></td>
        <td><input align="right" style="width:100px;" class="form-control" type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo '$' . $total = $c["q"] * $precio; /*aqui multiplico la cantidad enviada * por el precio*/?>"readonly></td>
        <?php $totalProducto += $total;/*sumo todos los valores totales*/ ?>
    </tr>
</table>

     </form>
     <?php
    endforeach;
   ?>
```

hasta qui todo funciona bien ya que me suma todos los valores dentro de mi foreach
Ahora nesecito igual sumar los valores pero ahora estos con un SELECT para cambiar la cantidad ya que la cantidad $c["q"] me envia de otro formulario            pero ya no puedo con la nueva cantidad ya que estaria conteniendole con el name="total" creo seria de hacerle algo pero no se me ocurre como
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el segundo caso
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se entiende bien tu problema.. podrias explicarlo mejor?

Comment: ya se puede visualizar @gbianchi porfa

Comment: Por favor, no dejes como comentario el problema. Sacalo afuera, explica bien el problema (sigue sin entenderse). Pone un ejemplo de los datos que tenes y que resultado tenes y cual te gustaria obtener.

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres hacer.  Quieres sumar los valores del select `cantidad`?

Comment: Sé un poco más específico, no está claro

Comment: No, @alanfcm lo que quiero es volver a sumar los totales, pero ahora ya se cambio la cantidad no se vuelve a multiplicar en el input total

Comment: Por eso, quieres el total de los valores de los select con `name=cantidad` despues de que el usuario cambia los valores?

Comment: Le volvi a modificar ya con una captura

Comment: Ok. Ahora se entiende el problema. PHP es un lenguaje que se ejecuta en el servidor. Deberias recargar la pagina con ajax (para que no se refresque toda) o utilizar js para calcular el valor en cada cambio del combo. Algun experto podra darte una solucion mas acorde. Pero si intentaste algo de eso, comentalo...

Comment: Si puedes pon el codigo de la función operacion y revisa que creo que copiastes tu codigo mal en la pregunta en la parte donde pones el valor al input llamado total, pues la operación contiene una variable $preci y sin embargo creo ke es $precio.

Comment: Ya edite y le puse la función es la misma que me ayudaste la anterior ves, @Dariel en el $precio ya le puse pero igual sigue sin funcionar, mira hasta cuando paso la cantidad del anterior formulario todo va bien pero ya al momento de cambiar ahora en este nuevo formulario la cantidad ya no funciona o sea ya no hace el re calculo como lo indico en las imágenes, por favor si me puedes ayudar te agradezco de ante mano

Comment: Veo que si se te está sumando la cantidad total en el formulario donde dice: "Total" y quieres también se muestre en "Total en compras" pero en ninguna parte colocaste el código de "Total en compras" para ver que está fallando. 

Si hace la suma, solo no te la pone donde esperas porque no se lo estás diciendo con cada onchange. 
Solo estas diciendo que lo pinte en el mismo formulario y no en el espacio de "Total en compras"

Answer (score 0):

prueba estos cambios:

```
//en el select cambias el valor de onchange ->
<select name="cantidad" style="width:100px;" class="form-control" onchange="operacion(this.value)">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function operacion(valor) {
       //Obtienes la cantidad
       var cantidad = parseFloat(valor); 
       //Obtienes el precio     
       var numero2 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("precio")[0].value);
       //Cambias en valor en el total
       document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = ( numero1 * numero2 );                                                                              
}    
</script>
```

Comment: luego puedes hacer el código mas elegante....